# Why is my image in the header section not showing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have added an image in the header section as a logo.But the image is not showing.However the code is working for my online course instructor.I have tried various images and links but in vain.

I have given the link of my github repository of the codes I used:
https://github.com/Ashikf1/web-des-ign

Though I see nothing wrong with the code still it isn't working.I would be grateful if anyone can help me out.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't make us to follow external links. As you can add the relevant information within the question it self.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the image path. As the image `logo.png` exists in `img` folder which is one level above the current css

try this

```
#logo-img {
    background: url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam Why it should be `url('img/logo.png')`. Because the images and css are resides in different folders.

Comment: You are right. My apologies. I was writing internal CSS. That's why I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

For images, use the image tag with src attribute:

```html
<image src="./img/logo.png" id="logo-img" alt="Logo image">
```

Comment: The ```src``` should be ```img/logo.png```